# Show custom tabs on specific user role profiles in Youzer plugin?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I made a custom tab in youzer profile and I need to show it to specific roles' profiles only. 
Please let me know any hooks that I can use to accomplish this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to change the tabs using a filter. (`$bpCoreNavItem` is an instance of `BP_Core_Nav_Item`)

```
function filterProfileTabs(array $tabs) {
    $newTabs = [];
    foreach ($tabs as $bpCoreNavItem) {
        if ($bpCoreNavItem->slug !== 'posts') {
            $newTabs[] = $bpCoreNavItem;
        }
    }
    
    return $newTabs;
}
add_filter('yz_profile_primary_nav', 'filterProfileTabs');
```

In that code I'm simply removing the "Posts" tab when finding it by its slug. To remove items based on user roles, you'll want to look up the user's role and implement any logic based on the given role. (Ex. Only remove "Posts" for users without the `administrator` role or the like.)